# Экспорт из OpenCart в WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, xml, парсер, woocommerce, opencart

Есть сайт на `OpenCart` версия 3.0.1.2, с которого нужно экспортировать товары на сайт, который использует `Woocommerce` версии 3.3.4. Экспортироваться будет через модуль `CSV Price Pro import/export OC3`. Сейчас все товары имеют простой вид. Как возможно экспортировать простые товары из `OpenCart` вариативными в `Woocommerce`? Парсеры ранее не делал, буду признателен за литературу и напутствия.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

> Как возможно экспортировать простые товары из OpenCart вариативными в
>   Woocommerce?

Парсеры не нужны. Нужно в сsv-файле поменять.

Comment: Поменять имеется ввиду заголовки? Не могли бы более детально описать это?

Comment: @ВладЮдкин поменять тип товара и всё другое, что нужно.

Comment: Есть ли туториал по таким делам?

Comment: Конечно. F1 в экселе